# Losing dependency on loop variables - loop optimization

Tags: c, optimization

I have the following nested loop computation:

```
int aY=a*Y,aX=a*X;
for(int i=0; i<aY; i+=a)
{
    for(int j=0; j<aX; j+=a)
    {
        xInd=i-j+offX;
        yInd=i+j+offY;
        if ((xInd>=0) && (xInd<X) &&
            (yInd>=0) && (yInd<Y) )
            {
             z=yInd*X+xInd;
            //use z
            }
     }
}
```

I want to lose the dependency on `i`,`j`,`xInd` and `yInd` as much as possible. In other words, I want to "traverse" all of the values `z` receives while running through the loop, but without involving helping variables `i`,`j`,`xInd` and `yInd` - or at least have a minimal number of computations involved (most importantly to have no multiplications). How can I do that? Other hints to possible ways to make the loop more efficient would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Can you state the nature of `a`, `Y`, `X`? The answer will be different if they are constant or variable.

Comment: Why is it important that you have no multiplications. What architecture are you targeting?

Comment: Does the order of iterations have to remain exactly the same? Can this be parallelized?

Comment: Are you not missing a pair of brackets ?

Comment: @cmh They are constant. a is an angle and X,Y are the width and height of an image, respectively. It is an exercise on optimization. We've learned that multiplication is a relatively costly operation. This might be tested on a system with slow multiplication

Comment: @tohava The order does not have to stay the same as long as every value of z is received once.

Comment: Your question implies that you've profiled and found this loop to be the problem, and then looked at the resulting assembler code to determine that what you're describing would actually help.  Is this the case?

Comment: Is `z` used to index a memory access? This would also change the nature of the answer.

Comment: @cmh yes, it is an index of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we read the question as how to mimimize the number of iterations around the loop, we can take the following approach.

The constraints:

```
(xInd>=0) && (xInd<X)
(yInd>=0) && (yInd<Y)
```

allow use to tighten the bound of the for loop. Expanding `xInd` and `yInd` gives:

```
0 <= i - j + offX <= X
0 <= i + j + offY <= Y
```

Fixing `i` allows us to rewrite the second loop bounds as:

```
for(int i=0; i<aY; i+=a) {
    int lower = (max(i + offX - X, -i - offY) / a) * a; //factored out for clarity.
    int upper = min(i + offX, Y - i -offY);
    for(int j=lower; j<=upper; j+=a) {
```

If you know more about the possible values of `offX`, `offY`, `a`, `X` and `Y` further reductions may be possible.

Note that in reality you probably wouldn't want to blindly apply this type of optimisation without profiling first (it may prevent the compiler from doing this for you e.g. [gcc graphite](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Graphite)).

**Use as index**

if the value `z=yInd*X+xInd` is being used to index memory, a bigger win is achieved by ensuring that the memory accesses are sequential to ensure good cache behaviour.

Currently `yInd` changes for each iteration so poor cache performance will potentially result.

A solution to this issue would be to first compute and store all the indicies, then do all the memory operations in a second pass using these indicies.

```
int indicies[Y * X];
int index = 0;
for(...){
    for(...){
        ...
        indicies[index++] = z;
    }
}
// sort indicies
for(int idx = 0; idx < index; idx++){
    z = indicies[idx];
    //do stuff with z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that offX and offY are 0, and replace your '<'s with '<='s, we can get rid of i and j by doing this:

```
for (yInd = 0; yInd <= aX + aY; ++yInd)
    for (xInd = max(-yInd, -aX); xInd <= min(yInd, aY); ++xInd)
```